# Simple PROLOG issue: How do you test multiple queries against your Prolog database?

Tags: database, prolog, gnu-prolog

I have a Prolog database file (test_inserts.p) that I used to insert all my data.

I also have a Prolog query file (test_queries.pl) that has all of the Prolog queries I wrote up to receive specific information from my database.

I was wondering how to actually use the test_queries.pl queries against my test_inserts.p database file when using **gprolog?** I was hoping there would be a way to load both at the same time, and somehow be able to command which query to run, instead of having to re-type each query that I wanted to run....

Answer (score 5):

I've used `initialization/1` ISO directive in `test_queries.pl` to get the effect you see at bottom.

test_queries.pl

```
test :-
        findall(_, (a(X,Y), format('~w ~w~n', [X,Y])), _).

:- initialization([test_inserts]).
:- initialization(test).
```

test_inserts.pl

```
a(X,Y) :- append(X,Y,[1,2,3]).
```

then call gprolog with `--consult-file`

```
gprolog --consult-file test_queries.pl
GNU Prolog 1.4.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 Daniel Diaz
compiling /home/carlo/test_queries.pl for byte code...
/home/carlo/test_queries.pl compiled, 5 lines read - 659 bytes written, 28 ms
compiling /home/carlo/test_inserts.pl for byte code...
/home/carlo/test_inserts.pl compiled, 2 lines read - 379 bytes written, 30 ms
[] [1,2,3]
[1] [2,3]
[1,2] [3]
[1,2,3] []
| ?-
```

Comment: +1. BTW, there is [GNU Prolog 1.4.1](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/unstable/?C=M;O=D)