# how can I make prolog print query results when running a prolog script

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I'm new to prolog and want to save all queries in a file instead of typing them by hand.

I have these facts in `facts.pl`:

```
likes(wallace, cheese).
likes(grommit, cheese).
likes(wendolene, sheep).

friend(X, Y) :- \+(X = Y), likes(X, Z), likes(Y, Z).
```

After reading the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059701/simple-prolog-issue-how-do-you-test-multiple-queries-against-your-prolog-databa),
I come up with the following code `queries.pl`:

```
main :-
    write(likes(wallace, cheese)),
    halt.

:- initialization(['facts.pl']).
:- initialization(main).
```

Here I want to examine if `likes(wallace, cheese)` holds,
what I expected is outputing something like `yes` or `no` but the actual output is `likes(wallace, cheese)`

I've googled a lot and attempted

`X = likes(wallace, cheese), write(X).`

`X is likes(wallace, cheese), write(X).`

`X := likes(wallace, cheese), write(X).`

but none of them works.

It might be a really easy question for you, but I have no idea about how to get things right.

BTW, I'm using GNU Prolog 1.4.1

Comment: Seven Languages in Seven Weeks, huh? :) Thanks for asking, the answer helped me out as well!

Comment: This online interpreter might be useful to others as well: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a way to 'tag' each query: here a simple way

```
query(likes(wallace, cheese)).
query(likes(mickey, whisky)).

% service predicates, check the library and use that if available
forall(X,Y) :- \+ (X, \+ Y).
writeln(T) :- write(T), nl.

main :-
    forall(query(Q), (Q -> writeln(yes:Q) ; writeln(no:Q))),
    halt.
```